# Access WordPress Database on Docker Volume

Tags: php, database, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I set up a WordPress Docker environment locally using docker-compose and everything works fine.

Here is the docker-compose file used:

```
version: "3" 
services:
# mysql container
   db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
# php myadmin Container   
   phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      PMA_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
# wordpress Container
   wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:php8.1-apache
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:80" # http://localhost:8000
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
     ["./:/var/www/html"]

volumes:
  mysql: {}
```

The site has been updated with contents. posts, etc

I was planning to migrate to live and I ran

```
docker compose down #no backup yet
```

After I issue

```
docker compose up # to backup the wordpress db
```

The WordPress direct to new installation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbZE.png)

I tried to inspect the volumes and identified mysql_db volume and wordpress volume
and renamed them msql_vol and wdp_vol respectively.

Updated docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3" 
services:
# mysql container
   db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
     - "mysql_vol:/var/lib/mysql"
# php myadmin Container   
   phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      PMA_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
# wordpress Container
   wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:php8.1-apache
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:80" # http://localhost:8000
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
     - "wdp_vol:/var/www/html"

volumes:
  mysql_vol:
    external: true
  wdp_vol:
    external: true
```

I ran docker compose build && docker compose up -d
but still can't get site back.

I check the $table_prefix (not applicable as I have not migrate the container yet)

I needed to get build a working container from the previous volume or have access to database inside the "wdp_vol" wordpress volume
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7bgr.png)

Comment: You had no volumes declared so the docker container created an anonymous one when it started (as [instructed](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/1bfa4724fe112b4246672ed2b3c42142f17d5636/8.0/Dockerfile.oracle#L116) when the image was built). When you downed/up, it created a new anonymous volume. I suspect you found that second (empty) volume and not the previous one. Just find that original volume (if you did not delete it yet...) and start your db against it.

Comment: Thanks. I found the original volume. But now I am trying to get an entry point for the old db inside the volume: /var/lib/docker/volumes/wdp_vol/_data

How can I get an entry point to direct the wordpress to use the old db.

Comment: Just name the volume as you did for the wrong one.